# Redis Client Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, koa, node-redis

I am attempting to connect to ElastiCache from my Koa-based Node.js application, which is deployed on an EC2 instance. Initially, the application successfully establishes a connection to the Redis instance. However, later on, the application attempts to connect to localhost, i.e., 127.0.0.1:6379.

Redis version: 7.x
Redis npm package: 4.x

> Error:
> info: Redis Connected Successfully
>
> Redis Client Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
> {
> errno: -111,
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '127.0.0.1',
> port: 6379
> }
> Redis Client Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
> {
> errno: -111,
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '127.0.0.1',
> port: 6379
> }
> events.js:377
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ec2-user/logs/logs.log'
>
> Emitted 'error' event on  instance at:
> at WriteStream. (/home/ec2-user/uc-server/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js:490:16)
> at WriteStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at WriteStream.emit (domain.js:475:12)
> at internal/fs/streams.js:335:14
> at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:179:23)
> {
> errno: -2,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'open',
> path: '/home/ec2-user/logs/logs.log'
> }

App.js:

```
const { createClient } = require('redis');
const session = require('koa-session');

app.keys = [CONFIG.APP_CONFIG.KEY]
console.log("REDIS HOST: ", REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT, CONFIG.REDIS_AUTH);
const client = createClient({url: `redis://:@${REDIS_HOST}:${REDIS_PORT}`});
app.use(session({
  store: {
    async get(key) {
      return await client.get(key);
    },
    async set(key, value) {
      return await client.set(key, value);
    },
    async destroy(key) {
      return await client.del(key);
    }
  },
  cookie: { domain: process.env.LOCAL_DOMAIN ? 'localhost': 'xxx.com', maxAge: 15552000/* , path: "/api" */ },
  key: '_09dfbb',
  maxAge: 15552000,
  renew: true,
  ttl: 15552000,
  rolling: false
}, app))
```